# Resume stripe subscription on payment date and not on original renewal date

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I have a typescript app with integrated stripe subscriptions to it. An example subscription is the monthly plan, let's say it's for $10 and it is set on auto-renew subscription. I want to handle a challenging edge case which is if a customer has an expired card on file and failed payment on the auto-renew date, Let's say that date is the 5th of January 2024, and then they decided to update their card 4 days later (9th of Jan), currently, my code does not update the next invoice date for the subscription from 5th of February to 9th of February, so the customer paid for a whole month but they missed 4 days of access.

I fixed my code and tried to listen to the invoice.payment_succeeded webhook and inside it I set the billing_cycle_anchor to 'now':

```
subscription = await this.stripeModule.updateSubscription(subscriptionId, {
                billing_cycle_anchor: 'now',
                proration_behavior: 'none',
            });
```

with this change, it is setting the dates as I want which is great, but what is happening is the customer getting invoiced twice, first the failed invoice is marked as 'Paid' and the customer is charged $10, and another invoice that is auto-generated on the subscription update by Stripe with $10 charge too.

The only way that I thought of is to add a code that refunds the customer one of the invoices, but I hope there is a better way than refunding the customer and preventing the customer from being invoiced twice in the first place. Can anyone guide me on how to handle this edge case, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's recommendation here is to keep giving access to your customer even if the first payment attempt failed. The idea is that Stripe will attempt to pay the Invoice again multiple times. It's extremely common for recurring payments to fail once and then succeed on the second attempt for example.

Because of that recommendation, what Stripe expects is that the period that is being paid includes the days before the payment succeeded. That's why Stripe doesn't "change" the Subscription or its Invoices because it assumes the service was still provided at that point. It's similar to how your phone or electricity provider doesn't cut access immediately if that makes sense.

The way you described your business model indicates that you do not want this approach though. Instead, as soon as the first payment attempt fails, you consider the Subscription "paused" in your system and will stop providing the service until they pay. This is not something Stripe offers directly today unfortunately so you have to work around it.

My recommendation here would be to get your end customer back "on session" (on your app/website) to enter card details. What you are planning to do in that case is basically to ignore the *currently opened Invoice* which hasn't been paid (the one in `latest_invoice`) and instead you want a brand new one for the brand new period that would start immediately (assuming they paid). What you can do is use the [Pending Updates](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates) feature that lets you test changes to a Subscription but only apply those changes for real **after** the resulting Invoice is paid.

When your customer is on your app, you call the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) and pass:

- `proration_behavior: 'none'` to not take into account the previous Invoice that is unpaid.
- `payment_behavior: 'pending_if_incomplete` to make sure that if the current payment attempt fails, the changes to the Subscription stay "pending"
- `expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']` to be able to get the new Invoice's PaymentIntent's client secret for confirmation client-side

At that point, the payment might just work with their current PaymentMethod on file in which case they are all set and have a brand new Invoice for a new period that just started.
Otherwise, the payment might fail (3DS needed, or just a card decline for example). In that case you now have a brand new PaymentIntent that you can use to confirm client-side with new payment method details. If the payment still fails, there's no real change to your Subscription, and if it succeeds they are all set again.
After that, you can void the previous Invoice to ensure no payment attempt is done on it again.

This is definitely more "convoluted" than it should be today but is unfortunately the best approach in this flow if you absolutely don't want to provide the service while the retries are happening.